# Hibernate transient field inside criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the field `domainLevel1` which will be computed inside it's getter `getDomainLevel1()`. And I use this field inside criteria.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_bbc_budgetkey")
public class BudgetKey implements JsonSerializable {

    .....

    @Transient
    private String domainLevel1;

    public String getDomainLevel1() {
        return "BLABLABLABLA";
    }

    .....
}

public List<BudgetKey> findByWord() {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                                      .createCriteria(BudgetKey.class);

    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("domainLevel1", "SEARCHME",MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

    return criteria.list(); // => EXCEPTION
}
```

But, `findByWord()` gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: 
          org.hibernate.QueryException: 
          could not resolve property: 
          domainLevel1 of: nl.xxx.BudgetKey
```

Am I allowed to use transient `domainLevel1` inside the criteria or should I follow an another way to filter with a field which is not releated with a column( with **criteria** of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `domainLevel1` is a **transient** variable and thus, is not mapped with any of the fields in table,thus you can't use it in Criteria